# Add new field to administration orders grid

Tags: orders, order-grid

I am building my first Magento plugin that will hook into the event of when an order is placed, and export the order to a third party web service.

Now, rather than creating a separate table to store each order and its export status, I want to use the existing Magento Order table. Is this possible?

Also- I would love to be able to add a button or two to the Magento Administration Order section. Is this possible ***without*** modifying core Magento files? I want this to be a plug and play Plugin that doesn't require modification to core files.

If not, I will have to create a new section that the administrator can track the export status of orders.

Answer (score 1):

**To add fields to order grid**

1. Create a custom magento module.
2. Using your module install script to add a field to table `sales_flat_order_grid`

   in /app/code/local/MagePal/ThirdPartyExporter/sql/thirdpartyexporter_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

   ```
   $this->run("
       ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('sales/order_grid')}` 
           ADD COLUMN `magepal_internal_order_num` INT NULL;

   ");
   ```
3. In your admin layout.xml add

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout>
   <add_order_grid_column_handle>
       <reference name="sales_order.grid">
           <action method="addColumnAfter">
               <columnId>magepal_internal_order_num</columnId>
               <arguments module="sales" translate="header">
                   <header>MagePal #</header>
                   <index>magepal_internal_order_num</index>
                   <type>text</type>
                   <width>110px</width>
               </arguments>
               <after>shipping_name</after>
           </action>
       </reference>
   </add_order_grid_column_handle>
   <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
       <update handle="add_order_grid_column_handle" />
   </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
   <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
       <update handle="add_order_grid_column_handle" />
   </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
   <layout>
   ```
4. To save/update `magepal_internal_order_num` in `sales_flat_order_grid`

   In /app/code/local/MagePal/ThirdPartyExporter/Model/Mysql4/Order.php

   ```
   public function updateOrderGrid($orderId, $array)
   {
       if(!is_array($array))
           return false;

       $db = $this->_getWriteAdapter();

       $db->update($this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
           $array, 'entity_id = '. $orderId);

       return true;
   }
   ```

   Then in /app/code/local/MagePal/ThirdPartyExporter/Model/Order.php

   ```
   public function updateOrderGrid($orderId, $uid)
   {
       return $this->getResource()->updateOrderGrid($orderId, $uid);
   }
   ```

   When you want to upgrade the info in sales_flat_order_grid you can now do

   ```
   Mage::getModel('thirdpartyexporter/order')->updateOrderGrid($order_id, array('magepal_internal_order_num' => 'your id here'));
   ```

You could also rewrite `sales_order_grid` see http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/

Answer (score 1):

**To add a buttons to your order view section**

You can either:

1. Rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View`. See [How to add new button to order view in Magento admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642599/how-to-add-new-button-to-order-view-in-magento-admin-panel)
2. Use observer/event. See [Order view page print pdf button magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513085/order-view-page-print-pdf-button-magento)

   Use `adminhtml_block_html_before` instead of `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`

   ```
   <adminhtml_block_html_before> 
     <observers>
       <YourModuleNamespace_YourModuleName>
         <class>moduleName/observer</class>
         <method>functionName</method>
         <type>model</type>
       </YourModuleNamespace_YourModuleName>
     </observers>
   </adminhtml_block_html_before>
   ```

   Then in your observer.php

   ```
   if ($block->getId() == 'sales_order_view' && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
   ```

   or
   Assuming that you DO NOT have any other module rewriting  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View` block (if you have a module that rewrite that module class name e.g `if(get_class($block) =='MagePal_Guest2Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View')`)

   ```
   if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View')
   ```