# Sorting custom column renderer

Tags: grid, sorting, column, sort, renderer

I have this column i added. How can i sort it? i can click on sort, but well it doesnt really sort right.

My grid looks like:

```
$this->addColumn('sn_suppliers_noos', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('purchase')->__('NOOS'),
            'index' => 'product_id',
            'renderer' => 'MDN_Purchase_Block_Widget_Column_Renderer_SupplyNeeds_Noos',
            'type' => 'number'
        ));
```

My renderer looks like:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {       

        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());        
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
        $value= $product->noos;

        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/how-to-sort-custom-renderer-column-in-magento-grid)

Comment: Well its not a duplicate. What you're linkin to isnt a custom attribute, and therefore it already lies in the array and not from a renderer, which would make it alot easier :O